# how to retrieve data from json in java android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to edit an android vpn app that it's own server list.

i have a json of my own with server data but don't know how to embed it.

This is how my json response looks

```
    [
[
"0",
"PL",
"Poland",
"warswaw",
"1.1.1.1",
"IKEv2",
"",
""
],
[
"1",
"AU",
"Australia",
"Sydney ",
"1.1.1.1",
"IKEv2",
"",
""
],
```

and this is the code in app

```
 JSONObject json_response = new JSONObject("http://example.com/json.php");
                JSONArray jsonArray = json_response.getJSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ServerArray[i][0] = json_object.getString("id");
               ;
                    ServerArray[i][1] = json_object.getString("file");
                    ServerArray[i][2] = json_object.getString("city");

                    ServerArray[i][3] = json_object.getString("country");
                    ServerArray[i][4] = json_object.getString("image");
                    ServerArray[i][5] = json_object.getString("ip");
                    ServerArray[i][6] = json_object.getString("active");
                    ServerArray[i][7] = json_object.getString("signal");
                    NumServers = NumServers + 1;
                }
```

the arrays are from old api https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gayanvoice/android-vpn-client-ics-openvpn/images/appdetails.json

how can i rewrite so that it reads my server list ?

Comment: it was not intended, changed post to your satisfaction

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) - it would be much easier for you.

Comment: changing the logic of retrieving data could affect the rest of the project. that's why I'm going with the same scheme, just don't know how to correctly parse it

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is of the format Array of Arrays of Strings. There are probably better ways to create your response using key-value pairs, but that's up to you.

You have to send a request to your endpoint to get the JSON response. In order to parse it, look at the format of your JSON response, and parse like so:

```
JSONArray rootArray = response.getJSONArray(); // Gets the root array
for(int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++){
    JSONArray childArray = rootArray.getJSONArray(i); // child array at index i
    for(int j = 0; j < childArray.length(); j++){
    // Traverse through and get strings using getString method on childArray
    }
}
```

Comment: i get cannot find symbol response

Comment: That's because you have to make a request to the URL of your server data and store that in a JSONObject response

Comment: really newbie at java and android. thank you for trying to help, no idea how to do that.

the JSON i have changes response dynamically. so the whole point is to update my db with servers and show in-app  that it changes servers list

Comment: `JSONObject json_response = new JSONObject("http://example.com/json.php");` this line is basically fetching the JSON from the URL "https...". Try putting your URL here?

I was exactly where you are a few months ago. Have a look at JSON Parsing and making HTTP requests to urls. If you're also writing the server code, learn about requests and how they work etc.

Comment: i have it declaread 

 private void GetAppDetails() {
            iv_server_refresh.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_servers_process));
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ServerActivity.this);
            queue.getCache().clear();
//            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gayanvoice/android-vpn-client-ics-openvpn/images/appdetails.json",
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http:/example.com/json.php?id=20",

Comment: you can see here how to file looks like https://github.com/gayanvoice/android-vpn-client-ics-openvpn/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/buzz/vpn/ServerActivity.java

Comment: Not sure why you're making a StringRequest when you're expecting a JSON. Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.